# Return specific data from SQL query and error invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SQL query below is returning the data I require, however on the table column "Payment status", "awaiting payment" and "paid" is returned for organisations, I want Payment Status (Paid/Unpaid) returned for companies and not the above.

I was thinking that this might be a where clause WHERE payment status only equals "Paid" AND "Unpaid", I tried to do this and I had a error

> invalid column name Payment_Status

Please advise how I can to only display Payment Status (Paid/Unpaid)

```
SELECT        
    Account.mm_registrationnumber AS CL_Reg_Number, 
    Account.Name, 
    Account.mm_supplierstatus AS Supplier_Status, 
    Account.PrimaryContactIdName AS Primary_Contact, 
    Account.EMailAddress1 AS Email, 
    Account.Telephone1 AS Telephone, 
    mm_address.mm_line1 AS Line1, 
    mm_address.mm_line2 AS Line2, 
    mm_address.mm_line3 AS Line3, 
    mm_address.mm_line4 AS Line4, 
    mm_address.mm_city AS City, 
    mm_address.mm_county AS County, 
    mm_address.mm_postcode AS Postcode, 
    mm_turnover.mm_name AS Signup_Turnover, 
    Account.mm_signupdate AS SignUp_Date, 
    mm_payment.mm_paymenttype AS Payment_Type, 
    mm_payment.mm_paymentstatus AS Payment_Status, 
    mm_payment.mm_vatamount AS Payment_Amount_VAT, 
    mm_payment.mm_paymentamount AS Payment_Amount_Net, 
    Invoice.InvoiceNumber AS Invoice_ID, 
    Invoice.DueDate AS Due_Date, 
    Invoice.CreatedOn AS Created_Date
FROM  
    Account 
INNER JOIN 
    mm_payment ON mm_payment.mm_organisation = Account.AccountId 
INNER JOIN 
    mm_address ON Account.mm_address = mm_address.mm_addressId 
INNER JOIN 
    mm_turnover ON Account.mm_turnover = mm_turnover.mm_turnoverId 
INNER JOIN 
    Invoice ON Invoice.AccountId = Account.AccountId
WHERE 
    Payment_Status = 'Paid'; //  error 'invalid column name Payment_Status'
```

Comment: Try `WHERE mm_payment.mm_paymentstatus`

Comment: SQL is a rather confusing language in that the various clauses of a  `SELECT` are not processed in an obvious (to beginners) order. Here's the SQL Server [documentation for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is you are referencing your column alias in your WHERE clause, not the column itself. Try this:

```
SELECT        Account.mm_registrationnumber AS CL_Reg_Number, Account.Name, Account.mm_supplierstatus AS Supplier_Status, 
                     Account.PrimaryContactIdName AS Primary_Contact, Account.EMailAddress1 AS Email, Account.Telephone1 AS Telephone, mm_address.mm_line1 AS Line1, 
                     mm_address.mm_line2 AS Line2, mm_address.mm_line3 AS Line3, mm_address.mm_line4 AS Line4, mm_address.mm_city AS City, 
                     mm_address.mm_county AS County, mm_address.mm_postcode AS Postcode, mm_turnover.mm_name AS Signup_Turnover, Account.mm_signupdate AS SignUp_Date, 
                     mm_payment.mm_paymenttype AS Payment_Type, mm_payment.mm_paymentstatus AS Payment_Status, mm_payment.mm_vatamount AS Payment_Amount_VAT, 
                     mm_payment.mm_paymentamount AS Payment_Amount_Net, Invoice.InvoiceNumber AS Invoice_ID, Invoice.DueDate AS Due_Date, 
                     Invoice.CreatedOn AS Created_Date

FROM            Account INNER JOIN
                     mm_payment ON mm_payment.mm_organisation = Account.AccountId INNER JOIN
                     mm_address ON Account.mm_address = mm_address.mm_addressId INNER JOIN
                     mm_turnover ON Account.mm_turnover = mm_turnover.mm_turnoverId INNER JOIN
                     Invoice ON Invoice.AccountId = Account.AccountId

WHERE mm_payment.mm_paymentstatus = 'Paid'; //  error 'invalid column name Payment_Status'
```

I also added your table name to the column for clarification. This will also fix a potential problem of having the same column name in any of your joined tables.

edit: If mm_paymentstatus is an integer or bit, try this, assuming 1 is 'Paid':

```
WHERE mm_payment.mm_paymentstatus = 1
```

Comment: just tried that and got an error saying Ambiguous column name 'mm_paymentstatus'.

Comment: Yeah I figured that might happen. Just updated the post to fix that.

Comment: now i got Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Paid' to data type int. in line 1

Comment: Is the data in mm_paymentstatus an integer or string? We can't see your data types.

Comment: its a integer mate

Comment: Ok, you can't compare integers to strings (well you can but the string has to be all integers and 'paid' is not an integer). Updated the Answer again for you.

Answer (score -1):

Please use
WHERE [Payment Status], as you have space in column name. So you need to use []